# About primes in an interval

Tags: prime-numbers

I find this result without a proof:

The prime number theorem implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $x > N$, there exists a prime between $x$ and $x(1 + \epsilon)$.

I am asking about a simple proof for this result.

Comment: What have you tried?  What other proofs might be relevant?  Does the infinitude of primes guarantee this result immediately?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: In fact I am tried the fact that $N(x)∼(x/(log x)), x→∞$  but without any sucess.

Comment: Using the prime number theorem, how many primes do you expect between $x$ and $x(1+\epsilon)$ in terms of $x$ and $\epsilon$? How does this value behave as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: @79037662: I have no idea.

Comment: In that case I will write an answer.

Comment: I think, Dusarts bounds for the number of primes below $x$ should be sufficient for a proof.

Comment: @Peter: But the Dusarts result is conditional

Comment: No, the Dusart bounds are proven for sufficiently large $x$ without relying on some unproven conjecture.

Comment: @Peter: In this case, any proof is very welcome.

Comment: I only read this in wikipedia, but I did not find a reference of a proof of Dusart's bounds. Anyway, you probably look for something easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By prime number theorem, there are approximately $\frac{N}{\ln(N)}$ primes less than $N$, for sufficiently large $N$. Therefore, between $x$ and $x(1+\epsilon)$ there are approximately $$\frac{x(1+\epsilon)}{\ln(x(1+\epsilon))}-\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$$ primes. This expression is equivalent to $$\frac{x(1+\epsilon)\ln(x)-x\ln(x(1+\epsilon))}{\ln(x(1+\epsilon))\ln(x)}$$ which, by L'Hopital's rule, approaches $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

In particular, this means there is some $N$ such that for all $x>N$ we have at least one prime between $x$ and $x(1+\epsilon)$.